# How can I get the Responses Body in URLSession Swift?

Tags: swift, api, urlsession

) I'm trying to get the Error messages from the response's body to post request. 
Here is the example of my code:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { _, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
            } else {
                print(response.?????)
            }
```

What should I do to see the responses body?

Comment: Hi @RolandMP, try to print the `response.debugDescription` ( use autocompletion to see if this exist ) and then you see if it has an '.body' to retrieve, then you will know what to looking for. Or, use Alamofire, very complete request used for meny developers. Give i try! Let me know

Comment: `_, response, error`: Why did you used "_" for the first Data parameter? What about reading that one?

Comment: @daniel-arantes-loverde thanks a lot with your help, you helped. I tried to use pods, but due to the usage of this code in UI autotests for the project without cocoa in it - I cannot import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the first parameter in the closure (_, response, error), and actually there is your data. Check the Apple sample to understand more https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for